# Front end calculation in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do a calculation on the front end of my app in flutter. I have a value and simply want to show twice that number. For example,

```
new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              rowCell(
                                  snapshot.data['totalquestions'], 'Answers'),
                              rowCell('£ 200', 'Earned'),
                            ],
                          ),
```

where the amount earned simply is the number of answers*2.

What would be the best way of displaying this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ***$* operator** in the string.

```
'£ ${value * 2} Earned' //value is variable you are changing
```

If value equals 200, it returns: *£ 400 Earned*

Comment: this only gives me the value twice, e.g. 200200 instead of 400

Comment: Your variable value must be of type int